# Html.ValidationMessageFor( MyKey ) without being tiedto a model's attribute?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, modelstate, asp.net-mvc-validation, asp.net-mvc-ajax

My model does not really represent what my form is posting. Example my Orgs Model which holds orgs helps me generate a treeview the users selects several nodes of the orgs tree and submits a form. The form posts an array[] or org ids.

(maybe i'm doing this all wrong, please let me know tried binding to models and that was confusing when dealing with trees grids etc and using partial views and ajax returning partial views and editorfor's etc.. the default model binding was useless)

anyways back to my point, since I want to validate if any orgs get selected:

```
if (SelectedOrgs == null) //array[]
{
    ModelState.AddModelError("OrgsNotSelected",IValidationErrors.OrgsNotSelected);
}
```

my question is how do i retrieve this random key that i just made up from my view? my model and even my viewmodel do not have an array for the selection this is just the result of the post.

I'm not sure what to do in the view to get the value for "OrgsNotSelected".

Thank you!
Bilal

Comment: Why not use a resource file, and just pass an empty key to the model state erro... Something like: 

ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, Resource.CustomError);

Comment: It seems like my issue was related to Ajax, I found a way to get the value from my view but since i use Ajax I'm not able to directly display the errors inside my page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you were doing normal submit actions to your controller, you would need to use the ValidationSummary to display errors that are not attached to a specific property.

As you are using Ajax, you would be better off returning a json result from your controller and you can define this so that it includes your errors in a format you can use in the success function to display your messages.

Comment: Thanks Steve. That's exactly what I am testing right now. Im adding my validation messages the modelstate which i pass to a helper method that return a json object to me and im passing the Json back to the view. However since my modelstate has errors Im using (not the success) part of my ajax form but the onError, does that make sense? Should i use on Success instead? I guess i can avoid model state completely and this way the json object can determine if i have errors or not in the view?

Comment: Your ajax will only execute the error function if it fails to get a response from your controller. You should use the success function and identify from your json data whether it is an error or not.